# Multiple Dropdown in Visual Studio 2008 not filtering correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, parameters

I am using Visual Basic 2008 SSRS and the backend is SQL Server 2008 to create reports.  I am trying to create 2 parameterized dropdowns that a user can select from in order to filter the data in the reports.  For some reason I can't seem to get both parameters to filter only one filters correctly.  When I run the report in visual studio 2008 I choose DROPDOWN1 equal to 2 and DROPDOWN2 equal to 4.  So it should only show one row, but for some reason only the second filter seems to work.  Do I just need to modify my sql maybe??  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
**Table 1**      **Table 2**                **Table 3** 
Key1        Key2    Data1       Key3    Data2   Data3
1           1       HI          2       GREEN   WHITE
4           1       YOU         2       GREEN   WHITE
            2       HEY         3       RED     BLACK
            3       HI          1       ORANGE  PURPLE
            1       HEY         4       BLUE    BLACK
            4       HEY         4       BLUE    PURPLE



**Current Result**              **Desired**     
Data1   Data2   Data3       Data1   Data2   Data3
HI      ORANGE  PURPLE      HI      ORANGE  PURPLE
HEY     BLUE    PURPLE              

**Parameters-** @DROPDOWN1- Available Values
Label Value
HIHEY   1
HI      2

**@DROPDOWN2- Avilable Values**
Label     Value
GREENBLUE   3
PURPLE      4

Query Designer- SELECT L.Key1, 
C.Data,
aa.Data2,
aa.Data3

 FROM Table1 AS L INNER JOIN Table2 C ON L.Key1 = C.Key2
 INNER JOIN Table3 aa on L.Key1 = aa.Key3 

 WHERE
((@DropDown1= 1 AND C.Data1 ='HI' OR C.Data1 ='HEY' )
OR
(@DropDown1= 2 AND C.Data1 ='HI'))

 AND

 ((

 (@DropDown2= 3 AND aa.Data2 IN ('GREEN', 'BLUE'))  
 OR
 (@DropDown2= 4 AND aa.Data3 ='PURPLE') 

 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure about the logic, but from your desired result, the OR clause in your Where condition needs to be bracketed.

```
((@DropDown1= 1 AND (C.Data1 ='HI' OR C.Data1 ='HEY') )
```

A demonstration of the full codes:

```
declare @table1 table (key1 int)
declare @table2 table (key2 int, data1 varchar(10))
declare @table3 table (key3 int, data2 varchar(10), data3 varchar(10))

insert into @table1 select 1 union all select 4

insert into @table2 
values
(1, 'HI'), 
(1, 'YOU'), 
(2, 'HEY'), 
(3, 'HI'), 
(1, 'HEY'), 
(4, 'HEY')

insert into @table3
values
(2, 'GREEN', 'WHITE'),
(2, 'GREEN', 'WHITE'),
(3, 'RED', 'BLACK'),
(1, 'ORANGE', 'PURPLE'),
(4, 'BLUE', 'BLACK'),
(4, 'BLUE', 'PURPLE')

select * from @table1
select * from @table2
select * from @table3

declare @DropDown1 int = 2, @DropDown2 int = 4

SELECT L.Key1, C.Data1,aa.Data2,aa.Data3
 FROM @table1 AS L  JOIN @table2 C ON L.Key1 = C.Key2
    INNER JOIN @table3 aa on L.Key1 = aa.Key3 
 WHERE (
 (@DropDown1= 1 AND (C.Data1 ='HI' OR C.Data1 ='HEY') )
OR
(@DropDown1= 2 AND C.Data1 ='HI'))

 AND
 ((
 (@DropDown2= 3 AND aa.Data2 IN ('GREEN', 'BLUE'))  
 OR
 (@DropDown2= 4 AND aa.Data3 ='PURPLE') 
 ))
```

Comment: Wow such a simple SQL error it was driving me nuts why the filter wasn't working.  Thank you so much!